# Elements of array are nil in loop

Tags: ruby, null

I want to concat ranges following some rules. It works fine until I try to do it in cycle. Here is the code.

```
class Range
  def +(range)
    (self.begin..range.end) if self.end < range.end && range.include?(self.end)
  end
end

ary = [(1..2), (1..3), (3..4), (0..9)]
buf = ary[0]
i = 0
while i < ary.size
  buf = buf + ary[i] #=>undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
  i+=1
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Range#+` method returns `nil` when `if` condition is false. Here's what happens:

```
class Range
  def +(range)
    puts "me: #{self}"
    puts "him: #{range}"
    res = (self.begin..range.end) if self.end < range.end && range.include?(self.end)
    puts "returning #{res.inspect}"
    res
  end
end

ary = [(1..2), (1..3), (3..4), (0..9)]
buf = ary[0]
i = 0
while i < ary.size
  buf = buf + ary[i]
  i+=1
end
# >> me: 1..2
# >> him: 1..2
# >> returning nil
```

### Solution?

Stop making unidiomatic loops and use the [power of standard library](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce). 99 of 100 times when you want to iterate a collection by manually tracking/updating current index - it's a bad idea. When you're new - it's 100 of 100.

```
ary = [(1..2), (1..3), (3..4), (0..9)]
ary.reduce(:+) # => 1..9

# >> me: 1..2
# >> him: 1..3
# >> returning 1..3
# >> me: 1..3
# >> him: 3..4
# >> returning 1..4
# >> me: 1..4
# >> him: 0..9
# >> returning 1..9
```

Comment: @squiguy: that method was in the question. I just used it.

Comment: And if you do need to know the current index, it's typically better to use `with_index` with a normal collection method.